# How to script the download of "undownloadable" flash clip and then upload to youtube?

Tags: download, flash, youtube, flv

I am trying to find a way to upload the following flash replay to youtube easily

http://battlestations.mobileweapon.net/history_view.php?hid=274641

I want to do these for a large number of replays from the site. Problem is, I can't download the swf or flv somehow even after trying various flash downloader tools, such as Flashgot firefox extension.

Can anyone enlighten me as to why I can't download the replay for viewing locally, and briefly outline a way to script the  uploading to youtube?

Answer (score 0):

try http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/9789 its a greasemonkey script for facebook flash videos. I havent tried it personally but it looks like if you are on facebook you should be able to save the flv file with it

Comment: ok nevermind. I just googled some more... http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=18063885304&topic=27075 apparently the replays themselves are just text files that are interpreted by the game itself so there is no video that can be saved from what i gather the way it is set up now. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks. Any idea if there is a way to do this via screen recording and then upload to youtube using a script?

Comment: depending on your operating system there is software to record the screen but are you trying to automate it im confused why you need a script.